# Docker --build-arg ignored when using Content Trust in FROM instruction

Tags: docker, dockerfile, notary

I'd like to build an image using `ARG` and `DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST` activated, with Docker `v18.06.1-ce`

Dockerfile:

```
ARG tag
FROM busybox:${tag}
```

Run `docker build --build-arg tag=1.33.1 .` OK

Then, active Content Trust `export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1`

Re-run `docker build --build-arg tag=1.33.1 .` NOK

Error received :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 

error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.38/build?buildargs=%7B%22tag%22%3A%221.33.1%22%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: invalid reference format
```

Any idea how to fix this issue ?

**N.B**: only happens on `FROM` instruction